# Create Drawable with specific height

Tags: android

I want to create a drawable object with a width equal to the screen's width and display 3 images inside the drawable. I know the last part can be done using a LayerDrawable object, but I don't know how to set the drawable sizes. What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html
i hope this help..